# How can I create a user without setting the question and answer in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a fairly unique situation with Asp.Net.  An admin user must create any new user for the web site. Since somebody else is creating the new user, it doesn't make sense to have them create a security question and answer to recover the password for the new user.

However, I want to use the security question and answer in order to allow a user to reset their password. So I have requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" for my membership provider.

The problem is that because I have requiresQuestionAndAnswer set to true, I'm unable to create a new user without supplying a question and answer. Is there a way to get around this requirement when creating a new user?

Comment: Daft question ... why not just set requiresQuestionAndAnswer  to false? the side effect is that you are working around your security implementation instead of this valid and allowed scenario. That or just ask the user that information during the creation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue.  I ended up loading a dummy question.. "What color is the sky?".

Comment: I would use that in combination with "force password change on first login".

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a default question so the users can immediately change their password once they get access.

Of course, this means they had better not forget it...